# What steps would be required to port KVM to Apple's XNU kernel?

Tags: virtualization, kernel, linux-kvm, darwin

I have a few related questions I am having difficulty finding a firm answer for:

- Does the XNU kernel have a KVM port in progress already? I know KVM was ported to the illumos kernel. How feasible is to have the same done for XNU?
- Does the XNU have an equivalent to something like KVM? If not, what would be the most efficient* way of setting up a minimal VM host based off the XNU kernel?

*By efficient, I mean:

- Minimal RAM usage
- No need for a Desktop Environment
- No need for a Window Manager
- No need for X11 or equivalent
- The only necessary processes running should be related to the VM hosting process and networking

Comment: XNU in general, or macOS specifically?

Comment: @grawity I purposefully didn't mention Mac OS. I would prefer not to limit options as far as possible. But that said, I am envisaging a multi OS platform based on Apple Mac hardware. I am a QA and it would be great to be able to switch between operating systems on the fly with as minimal overhead as possible.

 Update: I didn't consider that the OS might make a difference to the porting process. From my limited knowledge the kernal would be modified, and then a package on the OS would be able to interface with the kernel. Is that not how it works? Do we also need to make a change to the OS?